# Running Hadoop with multiversion java

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, hadoop2

when Hadoop running, it has several components such as datanode, namenode, scheduler, container, etc, etc. Can I run datanode, namenode, scheduler in java 1.8 and mapreduce container in some modified java ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "scheduler" is part of YARN, which is responsible for running the MapReduce containers, therefore its not clear how you'd manage to get different `JAVA_HOME` variables between those services.

You cannot compile Java 9 code and expect it to run in Java 8 services, no.

Java 6/7 code should run within a Java 8 environment, but since both are end of life, you should work on upgrading them

If you're asking about using Oracle JDK with OpenJDK, then as long as you aren't including some very specific libraries from Oracle, like some `javax` packages,  you should be fine

Comment: So It's like this, So there are two version of openjdk the original one and the modified one. I want to run the MapReduce task in container with modified openjdk and the rest of hadoops services with the original one. Is it possible? how?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of modifications? JVM optimizations, or actually adding methods and classes?

Comment: jvm optimization

Comment: I don't see how that would affect anything code related or the base features of the servers